# branching svn remote folders

Tags: java, svn, version-control

I have a Java project managed in  SVN. This project has a remote folder - say - bin. When I create a branch from trunk, svn cp command is not copying this remote folder, but instead, it maintains the link back to the trunk. So, if somebody makes a breaking change on this file in trunk, then it is automatically reflects in feature or release branches and causes problems.

Is there a way to force SVN to copy this remote folder and all the contents under it? Or is there any other feature in SVN that lets me do this?